Split sheet into multiple workbooks, keeping formatting and sheet protection/locked cells
I have working code in a module to split data in a worksheet tab into over 50 new worksheets based on the value in column A.
I need to also
(1) copy the sheet protection/locked cells
(2) copy the formatting (i.e. header colours)
How do I adjust the code below to incorporate points 1 and 2?
Sub SplitSheetIntoMultipleWorkbooksBasedOnColumn()
    Dim objWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim nLastRow, nRow, nNextRow As Integer
    Dim strColumnValue As String
    Dim objDictionary As Object
    Dim varColumnValues As Variant
    Dim varColumnValue As Variant
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Set objWorksheet = ActiveSheet
    nLastRow = objWorksheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
        strColumnValue = objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value
        If objDictionary.Exists(strColumnValue) = False Then
           objDictionary.Add strColumnValue, 1
        End If
    Next
    varColumnValues = objDictionary.Keys
    For i = LBound(varColumnValues) To UBound(varColumnValues)
        varColumnValue = varColumnValues(i)
        Set objExcelWorkbook = Excel.Application.Workbooks.Add
        Set objSheet = objExcelWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        objSheet.Name = objWorksheet.Name
        objWorksheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy
        objSheet.Activate
        objSheet.Range("A1").Select
        objSheet.Paste
        For nRow = 2 To nLastRow
            If CStr(objWorksheet.Range("A" & nRow).Value) = CStr(varColumnValue) Then
               objWorksheet.Rows(nRow).EntireRow.Copy
               nNextRow = objSheet.Range("A" & objWorksheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
               objSheet.Range("A" & nNextRow).Select
               objSheet.Paste
               objSheet.Columns("A:F").AutoFit
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub


There's something missing. On one hand, this code will create 50 workbooks and you don't want to have that many workbooks open i.e. the code to save the workbooks is missing. On the other hand, if you want to add 50 worksheets to the source workbook, you cannot name them as the source worksheet i.e. you would probaby want to name them after the keys in the dictionary (distinct values in the criteria column). Now which is it? Workbooks or worksheets? BTW, there is also a 3rd 'legitimate' option to copy the 50 worksheets to a single workbook.

Export Sheet to Multiple Workbooks

Run this code as is and act according to the information in the message boxes. If you can't figure it out, feel free to leave a comment below.
Nothing significant will happen as long as you don't set IS_IN_TEST_MODE to False i.e. 2 new workbooks should be created (not saved), and you'll have to manually close them.

Sub SplitSheetIntoMultipleWorkbooksBasedOnColumn()
' Use something shorter and more user-friendly like 'ExportByName'.
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const CRITERIA_COLUMN As String = "A"
    Const DST_SUBFOLDER_NAME As String = "Items"
    ' The following two have to be 'in sync'!
    Const DST_FILE_EXTENSION As String = ".xlsx"
    Dim DST_FILE_FORMAT As XlFileFormat: DST_FILE_FORMAT = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Const IS_IN_TEST_MODE As Boolean = True ' Careful! There is no Undo!
    
    ' Reference the source objects.
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' If it's not, use 'ActiveWorkbook' instead.
    If Len(swb.Path) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The workbook """ & swb.Name & """ was never saved!", _
            vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim sName As String: sName = sws.Name
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim sRowsCount As Long: sRowsCount = srg.Rows.Count
    If sRowsCount < 2 Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim scrg As Range:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set scrg = Intersect(srg, sws.Columns(CRITERIA_COLUMN))
    On Error GoTo 0
    If scrg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source range is ""'" & sName & "'!" & srg.Address(0, 0) _
            & """. The criteria column """ & CRITERIA_COLUMN _
            & """ is out of bounds!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim ColumnsCount As Long: ColumnsCount = srg.Columns.Count
    
    ' Return the source data in arrays.
    
    ' If there are formulas that need to be preserved,
    ' use '.Formula' (or 'Formula2') instead of '.Value'!
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    ' Here you need values!
    Dim scData() As Variant: scData = scrg.Value
    
    ' Return the distinct values from the criteria array in the keys
    ' of a dictionary. Each corresponding item will hold a collection
    ' of the source rows.
    ' Also, calculate the maximum number of rows per value.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim sKey As Variant, sRow As Long, dRowsCount As Long
    
    For sRow = 2 To sRowsCount
        sKey = scData(sRow, 1)
        If Not IsError(sKey) Then
            sKey = CStr(sKey)
            If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
                If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then
                    dict.Add sKey, New Collection
                End If
                dict(sKey).Add sRow
                If dict(sKey).Count > dRowsCount Then
                    dRowsCount = dict(sKey).Count
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next sRow
    
    If dict.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are only errors or blanks in the criteria range ""'" _
            & sName & "'!" & scrg.Address(0, 0) & """!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Create a copy of the source worksheet in a new single-sheet workbook
    ' and clear the 'excessive' rows i.e. keep as many data rows
    ' as the maximum number of rows per value.
    ' This helper workbook with fewer rows will be repeatedly copied
    ' so fewer rows will have to be cleared.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    sws.Copy
    Dim cwb As Workbook: Set cwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
    Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = cwb.Sheets(1)
    cws.Range(srg.Address).Resize(sRowsCount - dRowsCount - 1) _
        .Offset(dRowsCount + 1).Clear
    
    ' For each key in the dictionary, create a copy of the helper workbook
    ' (the copy becomes the destination workbook),
    ' copy the matching rows from the source array to the destination array,
    ' copy the values from the destination array to the destination range,
    ' clear excessive rows and save and close the destination workbook.
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To dRowsCount, 1 To ColumnsCount)
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook, dws As Worksheet, drg As Range
    Dim RowItem As Variant, c As Long
    Dim dRow As Long, dFolderPath As String, dFilePath As String
    
    For Each sKey In dict.Keys ' distinct criteria
        ' Return the matching rows at the top of the destination array.
        dRow = 0
        For Each RowItem In dict(sKey) ' source row numbers in collection
            sRow = RowItem
            dRow = dRow + 1
            For c = 1 To ColumnsCount
                dData(dRow, c) = sData(sRow, c)
            Next c
        Next RowItem
        ' Create a copy of the helper workbook,...
        cws.Copy
        ' ... and reference this copy, the destination workbook.
        Set dwb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        Set dws = dwb.Sheets(1)
        'dws.Name = sName
        ' Return the values from the destination array in the destination range.
        Set drg = dws.Cells(1).Offset(1).Resize(dRow, ColumnsCount)
        drg.Value = dData
        ' Clear below.
        If dRow < dRowsCount Then
            drg.Resize(dRowsCount - dRow + 1).Offset(dRow).Clear
        End If
        ' Build the destination file path.
        dFolderPath = swb.Path & Application.PathSeparator _
            & IIf(Len(DST_SUBFOLDER_NAME) = 0, "", DST_SUBFOLDER_NAME _
            & Application.PathSeparator)
        If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir dFolderPath
        dFilePath = dFolderPath & sKey & DST_FILE_EXTENSION
        ' Save and close the destination workbook.
        If IS_IN_TEST_MODE Then
            Dim dCount As Long: dCount = dCount + 1
            dwb.Saved = True
            MsgBox "File " & dCount & " would have been saved as """ _
                & dFilePath & """!", vbExclamation
            If dCount = 2 Then
                MsgBox "Adjust the constants to get the desired paths." _
                    & vbLf & "Once they're satisfactory, set the " _
                    & """IS_IN_TEST_MODE"" constant to `False`!", _
                    vbCritical
                Exit For
            End If
        Else
            ' To overwrite without confirmation, ...
            ' prevent dialog if different format,... and whatnot.
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                dwb.SaveAs dFilePath, DST_FILE_FORMAT
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False ' just got saved
        End If
    Next sKey
    
    ' Close the helper workbook.
    cwb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Workbooks created.", vbInformation

End Sub

